# Change DHCP IP Pool Starting Address

Tags: dhcp

How can I change DHCP IP Pool Starting Address from `192.168.1.xxx` to `192.168.10.xxx`?

Comment: It's a router fucntion.  what router do you use?

Comment: I use ZyXEL router.

Comment: See if this pic that I found quickly via google helps you find what you are looking for: http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/ZyXEL/P-660HW-D1_v2/LAN_DHCP_Setup.htm

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am on the same page. I already try to change the IP Pool starting address from 192.168.1.xx to 192.168.10.xx but an error message at the bottom of the page displays 'Bad DHCP Pool Range' my current pool size is 32.

Comment: Did you specify a STARTING address of 192.168.10.1 or 192.268.10.xx?

Comment: I specify `192.168.10.1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19661/discussion-between-codefish06-and-tyson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish your objective by changing the modem's LAN IP address. It's impossible to specify a DHCP pool that is not in the same subnet as your modem. But if you change your modem's LAN IP address to 192.168.10.1, your DHCP pool will automatically be in the 192.168.10.x subnetwork. You can then change the start and end addresses for the pool.

Comment: On ZyXEL router, LAN TCP/IP, DHCP Setup and DNS Server are all in one page, so, After modifying the IP Address to 192.168.10.1, I also modify the IP Pool Starting Address changing its subnetwork. Thanks!